# How do I keep a summoned EnderDragon in a cage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I did /Summon in minecraft and I summoned an ender dragon. My friend and I thought it would be cool if we built a cage for the ender dragon. We build a huge cage out of end stone, obsidian and bedrock. We summoned the ender dragon in the cage, and it could fly right out of the cage. mobGriefing was off, and we used blocks that the ender dragon couldn't destroy. Is there any way we can keep him from flying out of a cage? The cage was definitely big enough for at least 3 ender dragons.

Answer (score 12):

With the new summon command 1.7.4, you can summon a enderdragon on a minecart. Then it will still look to you but it can't fly away. You can also give it custom names. :-) Here is the command.... you can make these commands with the new summon program

[image: the command]

[image: the enderdragon]

Answer (score 10):

As *FEichinger* [explained](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/152374), it's impossible keep an Ender Dragon in place using building blocks.

But you can continuously teleport the Dragon to the same location using a [Command Block](http://minecraftwiki.net/Command_Block) with the `/tp` command (**since [snapshot 14w02a](https://mojang.com/2014/01/minecraft-snapshot-14w02a/)** it can work on any entities, not just players).

[image: Command block contents]

Use a clock to repeatedly execute the command:

```
/tp @e[type=EnderDragon] X Y Z
```

And the Ender Dragon will be stuck in that location, but will shake quite a bit because it will try to move constantly...

[image: Stuck dragon]

Of course, you can add a cage around the Dragon as a cosmetic feature...

Comment: Is a good idea that would work but the dragons movement may be too limited.

Comment: This would be my best bet at doing it, but remember that the ender dragon CAN break command blocks. So make sure your TP circuit is a safe distance away. (but close enough that the same chunk is loaded)

Comment: Can you use a command block to apply the **slow** effect on a dragon to keep it in place?

Comment: That was a very good idea, @IQAndreas, but it seems like the Ender Dragon ignores the Slow effect.

Comment: You might be able to use logic gates to trigger the command block to teleport the dragon when it reaches the boundary of it's cage

Comment: @Memor-X /tp @e[type=EnderDragon,x=X,y=Y,z=Z,rm=Sizeofcage] X Y Z

Answer (score 9):

Any block the [Ender Dragon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Dragon) cannot destroy, it will [pass right through](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Dragon#Behavior).

This can easily be tested in a superflat world in creative mode. Spawning a dragon and luring it through the Bedrock leads to these results:

[image: Screenshot of a village razed by an Ender Dragon with a Bedrock layer intact]

As the screenshot shows, the Bedrock layer remains intact desipte the Dragon's attempts - And the dragon flies through it without a problem.

**Conclusion:** It is not possible to keep an Ender Dragon trapped in one location.

Comment: Seems like your conclusion is wrong. If one option doesn't work, that doesn't mean nothing will.

Answer (score 2):

you could have a command block repeating this command

```
/tp @e[type=EnderDragon,X,Y,Z,mr=minrange] x y z
```

The x y z would be the center of the cage, and the minrange = how big the cage is, so when ever the ender dragon went outside of the cage, it would be teleported back to the center

Answer (score 0):

to get to stay in one place in 1.7.2+ do

/summon EnderDragon ~ ~ ~ {Riding:{id:"MinecartRideable",Tame:true}}

and the dragon will stay in one place